# C# How To Draw a Rectangle On Images With Different Resolution?

Tags: c#, draw

i want to draw a rect that has a same size on images with different resolution.sorry if i couldent explain well, what i want is to draw a rectangle on an image but you know when (for example) i use RectangleF(0.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 200.0F) it will appear large on low resolution images and also small on high resolution images.

any help will be appreciated.

my code:

```
Color customColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Blue);
SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor);
// Create array of rectangles.
RectangleF[] rects = { new RectangleF(image.Width/2, 0.0F, 100.0F, 200.0F), new RectangleF(100.0F, 200.0F, 250.0F, 50.0F) };
g.FillRectangles(shadowBrush, rects);
```

Comment: 'image resolution' can mean pixel size or dpi. 'same scale' is also not really clear. Please eloborate your question!

Comment: @TaW sorry if i couldent explain well, what i want is to draw a rectangle on an image but you know when (for example) i use RectangleF(0.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 200.0F) it will appear large on low resolution images and also small on high resolution images.

Comment: Yes. You need to a) calculate the necessary scaling factors for each image and then b) scale the Graphics with it by doing a Graphics.ScaleTransform before drawing.

Comment: @TaW thank u for your reply.i am a beginner so would you please show me an example code in c# how to do it?

Comment: I suggest you experiment a little and when you run into problems you can update the question..

Comment: a) calculate the necessary scaling factors for each image and then :

RectangleF[] rects = { new RectangleF(0.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F, 100.0F)};
float sx=image.Width/100, sy=image.Height/100;

b) scale the Graphics with it by doing a Graphics.ScaleTransform before drawing:

g.ScaleTransform(sx, sy);
g.FillRectangles(shadowBrush, rects);

it didnt work :( @TaW

Comment: a) don't put code in comments, update the question. b) _it didnt work_ is an utterly useless problem description. c) your code suffers from integer division. change to maybe `../100f` But you need to understand what you're doing. Add the full numbers to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a base resolution eg: 80x60

Get the image resolution eg:

```
var imageWidth = image.Width;
var imageHeight = image.Height;
```

Calculate the scale of the base resolution to the users resolution:

```
var scaleWidth = imageWidth / 80;
var scaleHeight = imageHeight / 60;
```

Multiply your Rect's dimensions by the scale eg:

```
newX = baseX * scaleWidth, 
newY = baseY * scaleHeight, 
newWidth = baseWidth * scaleWidth, 
newHeight = baseHeight * scaleHeight
```

Wrote this answer on my phone so it is untested but it should be correct.

Comment: how can i use your solution to write text on image and auto scale text according to image resolution? @Xela